# Has any tried empty HA cluster template with Deployment Manager for RHEL 7 for sap provided by Google?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

I tried to build empty RHEL cluster on GCP using below google provide Deployment Manager template. The instances get provisioned but cluster never gets configured. Even the Deployment Manager failed to configure the password less authentication between servers. I am not able to find error or failure logs. Below is the template file provided by google.

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/sapdeploy/dm-templates/sap_emptyha/template.yaml


imports:
- path: https://storage.googleapis.com/sapdeploy/dm-templates/sap_emptyha/sap_emptyha.py

resources:
- name: sap_empty_ha
  type: https://storage.googleapis.com/sapdeploy/dm-templates/sap_emptyha/sap_emptyha.py
  properties:
    primaryInstanceName: sapci01
    secondaryInstanceName: sapci02
    primaryZone: us-central1-a
    secondaryZone: us-central1-b
    instanceType: n1-standard-2
    subnetwork: subnet-a
    linuxImage: family/rhel-7-6-sap-ha
    linuxImageProject: rhel-sap-cloud
    sap_vip: 192.168.0.101
    #
    # --- Advanced Options ---
    # The following advanced options are not usually needed. To use an advanced option, remove
    # the comment indicator, #, before the parameter name and specify an appropriate value.
    #
    networkTag: external,internal
    #    Adds network tags to your instance. This is useful if you do routing or define
    #    firewall rules by tags. By default, no tags are added to your VM. Multiple tags
    #    can be assigned by separating them with commas
```

Below is the deployment manager command

```
$ gcloud deployment-manager deployments create sap-empty --config rhel.yaml
```

Has any tried empty HA cluster template with Deployment Manager for RHEL 7 for sap provided by Google or anyone can figure out the issue?

Comment: Can you provide more details in regards to the issue you are facing? You mentioned that the instances are provisioned, but the cluster is not configured.Can you access the instances. Are the instances configured as per the configurations provided in the template?

Comment: Yes, Only VMs are provisioned and I am able to access the VMs. Nothing else happens. The same template is working for SuSE 12 sp4 for sap.